# Loop through AJAX appended list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, for-loop

im trying to loop through a list that is appended with data received from an AJAX call.

Basically, i made an AJAX call and used a loop to append the data to the list element in the DOM.

```
     users.forEach(function(user){
    $.getJSON(channelUrl + user, function(data){
          //DECLARE ARRAYS
          var channels = [];
          //PUSH DATA TO ARRAYS
          channels.push(data);
          //APPEND DATA TO DOM
          channels.forEach(function(channel){

              $('.stream-item').append(
                      `<h3>`+ channel.display_name + `</h3>
                       <span class="status"></span`); 
          })
     })
})
```

Then i'm trying to append "Offline" inside the span tag in each item based on the result of another AJAX call

```
   users.forEach(function(user){
    $.getJSON(streamUrl + user, function(data){
          if(data.stream){
            $('.status').append('Offline')
          }
          else
            $('.status').append('Online')
    })
  })
```

this is my html

```
    <div id="stream-list-container">
      <ul id="stream-list">
          <li class="stream-item">
            stream item
          </li>
      </ul>
```

The result of this was it appended "Offline" as many as the ajax data to each of the list item

here's the link to the project

http://codepen.io/kevinjanada/pen/MJZZmr?editors=1011

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: How do you know which `<span class="status">` will `offline` or `online`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to update the status for each time with the same class name i.e, so the status value is appended for all available class.

```
users.forEach(function(user){
    $.getJSON(streamUrl + user, function(data){
          if(data.stream){
            $('.status').append('Offline')
          }
          else
            $('.status').append('Online')
    })
  })
```

Instead while adding the status span try to add a id to it and update the status  of the user.

Kindly refer my changes made to your code below

```
$(function (){

  //==============================================
  //----------DECLARE USERS AND API URL-----------
  //==============================================

  const esl   = 'ESL_SC2',
        fcc   = 'freecodecamp',
        og    = 'OgamingSC2',
        cret  = 'cretetion',
        stor  = 'storbeck',
        hab   = 'habathcx',
        robo  = 'RobotCaleb',
        noob  = 'noobs2ninjas'

  const users     = [esl, fcc, og, cret, stor, hab, robo, noob];

  var streamUrl   = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/';
  var channelUrl  = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/';



  //==============================================
  //-------------MAIN FUNCTION--------------------
  //==============================================

  users.forEach(function(user){
    console.log(user);
    $.getJSON(channelUrl + user, function(data){
          //DECLARE ARRAYS
          var channels = [];

          //PUSH DATA TO ARRAYS
          channels.push(data);
          //APPEND DATA TO DOM
          channels.forEach(function(channel){
              //Check for the changes made
              $('.stream-item').append(
                      `<h3>`+ channel.display_name + `</h3><span class="`+user +`"></span>`); 
          });
     });
  });
  users.forEach(function(user){
    $.getJSON(streamUrl + user, function(data){
          if(data.stream){
            //Check for the changes made
            $('.' + user).append('Offline');
          }
          else {
            //Check for the changes made
            $('.' + user).append('Online');
          }
    });
  });

});
```

I added the user name as class instead of status as class name and update it later based on user name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked, and it appended offline and online to each list item.

Comment: However, the ajax call does not seem to be in order of the array.
So doing 2 ajax call made the whole thing out of sync
Any other suggestions?

Comment: I just found another approach that works, thanks again